# $Z$ has a standard normal distribution. $P(Z \in (-a,b)) = 0.95$ where $a,b > 0$. Find the derivative the length, $l$, of the interval $(-a,b)$.

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution, chain-rule

$Z$ has a standard normal distribution. $P(Z \in (-a,b)) = 0.95$ where $a,b > 0$. I'm asked to find the derivative the length, $l$, of the interval $(-a,b)$.
I have an expression for $l$ as a function of $a$: $l = a + \Phi^{-1}(0.95 + \Phi(-a))$. How do I go about differentiating this? I am allowed to express it in terms of $\Phi, \Phi^{-1}$ and $\phi$. I assume some application of the chain rule, but I am a bit confused on how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Was the answer below helpful? After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can chain rule to differentiate inverse functions. Let $g(x) =f^{-1}(x)$. Then we have that

$f(g(x)) = x$. Differentiating both sides, we get that $g'(x)f'(g(x)) = 1$. Thus, we get that $g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$. (Assuming the derivative is not zero, so we want functions without inflection points).

Thus in this case, we have that

$$l'(a) = 1 - (\Phi^{-1})'(0.95+\Phi(-a))\Phi'(-a) = 1 - \frac{\Phi'(-a)}{\Phi'(\Phi^{-1}(0.95+\Phi(-a)))} = 1 - \frac{\Phi'(-a)}{\Phi'(l(a)-a)}.$$

Comment: Ah okay, thank you so much! Just to double check, as the pdf is the derivative of the cdf at each point, I can then rewrite $\Phi'(u)$ as $\phi(u)$?

Comment: Yes, if $\phi$ is the pdf. I wasn't sure what $\phi$ was referencing so I left it as $\Phi'$ in my answer.